# Garbage Collection: need more explanation

Tags: java, garbage-collection, memory-management

I was reading [this](http://www.infoq.com/articles/9_Fallacies_Java_Performance) nice article but stuck on one sentence to get more idea about this.

What does this means (mentioned in point #8) 
"Allowing application threads to run alongside `GC` threads invariably results in application threads mutating the object graph in a way that would affect the liveness of objects."

Comment: The "object graph" is the set of existing objects and their references to each other.  Extrapolate from there.

Comment: Can you be more specific what part of the sentence you don't understand? Is it the concept of liveness? The object graph? Mutation?

Comment: In particular this: GC threads invariably results in application threads mutating the object graph.

Answer (score 2):

This simply means that implementing a concurrent garbage collection algorithm represents a specific challenge - both the GC and application are running concurrently and thus the GC algorithm must deal with situations when the object set is being modified by the application at the time of a GC phase.